# How old was Menashe when he was Yosef's assistant?

Tags: age, yosef

According to the midrash Yoseph appoints Menashe over grain logs, has him subdue both Shimon and Yehudah on two separate occasions, and even sends them after his brothers to "retrieve" his cup from Binyamin. But it seems, since the brothers come to Egypt at the end of the seven plentiful years that begin almost immediately, that Menashe couldn't have been older than eight years old at the most? Anybody have any sources on how old Menashe was at the time?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!